# How can I use PSBT in a JavaScript project?

Tags: javascript, bitcoinjs, bcoin, bip174-psbt

I am trying to use PSBT in a Bitcoin project.
The idea is to generate keys and sign transactions client-side.

I am already familiar with `bitcoinjs-lib` but I find the API rather complicated.
It would be great if I could use `bcoin` which is usually more clear and straight forward.

I checked the `bcoin` docs but I found no mention of PSBT.
Is there a way to use PSBT in `bcoin`?
If not, is there any elegant workaround?

Comment: I think PSBT is not available in bcoin yet: https://github.com/bcoin-org/bcoin/pull/607

Comment: Hey Mario, I reformatted a bit to structure the distinct thoughts into blocks and retitled the question, because I first thought that you were working on adding PSBT to bcoin, which from the text of your question doesn't seem to be the case. I also added some more tags to help people see the question that follow the corresponding topics. If I changed the intent of your question or misunderstood your intention, please rollback my edit or change it further to better fit your meaning.

Comment: @Murch Thanks for having rephrased the question in a more clear way.